# Is it possible to edit the Meta description from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

In the Master Page for Visual Studio 2005 website, I am using meta description as

```
<meta name="keywords" content="coupons, coupons, online coupons, health deals, health coupons, computer coupons, bargains, hot bargains" />
<meta name="description" content="<%=MyMetaDescription%>" />
```

I would like to replace the content in each aspx page. How do I use it? 
I get the same content as description though I have tried to replace the content in code behind page.

In the code behind, i have called Master.MyMetaDescription = "";

Can someone help me out on this. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Where are you setting the value for MyMetaKeyWords? Can you post that code?

Comment: That is MyMetadescription, i edited it. I used Master.MyMetadescription in code behind to edit it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Incidentally, this probably won't really do much for you: search engines mostly ignore that stuff nowadays...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuck has already provided a simple enough way to add meta content.

Regardless, see [this code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/PageTags.aspx) to see how meta tags can be added from code behind. It also provides a nice solution based on that to easily add meta tags to page.

Answer (score 3):

I would use this :

```
 this.Page.MetaKeywords = "football, sport, golf";
 this.Page.MetaDescription = "My site is all about football and golf";
```

Obviously if you just want to append to them then just use `+=` (don't forget a leading , for the keywords).

Answer (score 1):

Make a content placeholder where the `<meta>` tag will go in the `<head>` section:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID = "MetaContent" runat = "server" />
  </head>

<!-- other content -->

</html>
```

In your pages then you can replace the content using a different `<meta>` tag.

```
<asp:Content ID = "MyMeta" PlaceHolderID = "MetaContent" runat = "server">
  <meta />
</asp:Content>
```